# R - Split words from each obs. in dataframe into a new dataframe

Tags: r

With the following data frame:

```
 Query
1 word1 word2 word3
2 word4 word5
3 word6
4 word7 word8

df1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "Query
1 'word1 word2 word3'
2 'word4 word5'
3 word6
4 'word7 word8'")
```

I want create a new data frame with the following format:

```
 Query
1 word1
2 word2
3 word3
4 word4
5 word5
6 word6
7 word7
8 word8
```

Do you know of a R function or a R package able to do it? I am actually using the function word from stringr's package, but it seems to only being splitting the first word of every observation. For getting all words, I should have to calculate every row's bond (1, total number of words <- whitespaces + 1) and call the function within a "for" for every row, which is not optimal as my dataframe have more than 5M observations.

Comment: Why not just `unlist` after `strsplit`? Do you have other columns?

Comment: In other words, just `unlist(strsplit(as.character(df1$Query), "\\s"))`

Comment: Or if you already using `stringi`, this would be even quicker `unlist(stri_split_fixed(df1$Query, " "))`

Comment: I think ananda and akrun swapped accounts today :}

Comment: @DavidArenburg that would be more robust if you used `\\s+` but still works for the example given `data.frame(Query = unlist(strsplit(as.character(df1$Query), "\\s+")))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg, speculation or proof? I get faster performance with base R's `strsplit` with `fixed = TRUE`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto mainly speculations, though I was thinking there is some overhead when calling `as.character` in base compared to `stringi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(df1, 'Query', ' ', 'long')
#    Query
#1: word1
#2: word2
#3: word3
#4: word4
#5: word5
#6: word6
#7: word7
#8: word8
```

Comment: Thanks. It works like a silk. Some time is required as the data frame is large, but I am also using an old laptop. At work, with modern desktops, it should go really fast.

Answer (score 1):

I'm biased in favor of `cSplit` (and it should be reasonably fast even on 5M observations) however (converting my comment to an answer) you can also consider just using `strsplit` from base R, which is quite fast, especially if your delimiter is fixed:

```
data.frame(Query = unlist(strsplit(as.character(df1$Query), " ", TRUE)))
#   Query
# 1 word1
# 2 word2
# 3 word3
# 4 word4
# 5 word5
# 6 word6
# 7 word7
# 8 word8
```

Another approach comes from the Hadleyverse: Use `strsplit` and then `unest` from "tidyr".

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(Query = strsplit(as.character(Query), " ", TRUE)) %>%
  unnest(Query)
```

Comment: I would have also used `strsplit`, but I like the `cSplit` for its compactness. Great function!

Comment: @akrun, thanks. It's in dire need of some cleaning up, but I can't seem to get the time these days to work on my packages. PRs are welcome :-)

Comment: Hi @akrun and Ananda. Thanks for your answers. Both approaches also worked very well, and as I am not a performance freak, I didn't time every approach to see which one was faster. The script that updates my data needs actually a lot (and I always go to get me a cooffe meanwhile). However, I chosed akrun's approach because I use already splitstackshape for the stratified function and, as you say, it looks so cute and compact... Being the daddy from splitstackshape, I figure you understand my choice :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a memory efficient way of solving the problem in that I initalize a new data.table and modify by reference. This approach uses the data.table package.

```
library(data.table)
# define data.table
Query<- data.table(x = c("word1 word2 word3", "word4 word5", "word6", "word7 word8"))

# create list containing each word as a character vector in each row
Query[, x:= lapply(x, str_split, pattern = " ") ]

# determine number of words in each list/row
Query [ , length:= vapply(x, function(x) length(x[[1]]), numeric(1))]

# initialize data.table of length equal to number of rows needed
new_Query <- data.table(x = rep(NA_character_, sum(Query$length, na.rm =T)))

# loop through Query to assign the appropriate values to new_Query
j <- 1
for(i in 1:nrow(Query)){
  index2 <- j+Query[i, length]-1
  new_Query[j:index2, x := Query[i, unlist(x)]]
  j <- index2+1
}
```

Comment: Why not just `Query[, list(x = unlist(x))]` after the `str_split` step? Also, you should mention whatever packages are used in an answer.